# Why giving an environment variable to sudo su fails?

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, sudo

Putting PATH variable into `sudo su - USER` occurs an error:

```
USER1@SERVER:~:$ sudo PATH=$PATH su - USER2
sudo: sorry, you are not allowed to set the following environment variables: PATH
```

Following the [manual](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.28/sudoers.man.html#Denied_command_log_entries),

> The user specified environment variables on the command line that were not allowed by sudoers.

It seems that giving env variables is not allowed.

However, when I try with other commands,

```
USER1@SERVER:~:$ sudo PATH=$PATH printenv PATH
{PATH OF USER1}
```

```
USER1@SERVER:~:$ sudo PATH=$PATH -su USER2
USER2@SERVER:~:$
```

giving environment variables doesn't make any error.

I know that there are other good ways to switch to USER2, but I want to understand more about sudo/sudoers by figuring out why this happens.

Why does `sudo PATH=$PATH su - USER2` make an error, while `sudo PATH=$PATH -su USER2` works fine?

---

Some lines from /etc/sudoers that might be relevant.

```
Cmnd_Alias SU = /usr/bin/sudoedit, /usr/sbin/visudo, /sbin/sulogin, /sbin/sushell
Cmnd_Alias SWITCH = !/bin/su, !/bin/su -, /bin/su [-] *, !/bin/su - *root, !/bin/su root
...
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep = "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR ..." # doesn't contain PATH / I found that putting env variables of this list doesn't make an error.
...
USER1 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, !SU, SWITCH, !KRNMOD, !SHUTDOWN, !REBOOT, !HALT, !INIT
```

```
[USER1@SERVER ~]$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for USER1 on SERVER:
    syslog=auth, log_year, logfile=/var/log/sudo.log, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG
    LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS
    _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"

User USER1 may run the following commands on SERVER:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL, !/usr/bin/sudoedit, !/usr/sbin/visudo, !/sbin/sulogin, !/sbin/sushell, !/bin/su, !/bin/su -, /bin/su [-] *, !/bin/su - *root, !/bin/su root,
        !/sbin/insmod, !/sbin/rmmod, !/sbin/depmod, !/sbin/modprobe, !/sbin/shutdown, !/sbin/poweroff, !/usr/bin/reboot, !/usr/bin/consolehelper, !/usr/bin/halt, !/sbin/init
```

Answer (score 0):

The error about the inclusion of `PATH` denying your command is actually somewhat misleading.

The fundamental error is that your definition denies `sudo su - USER2`, so no matter what variables you try to define you will still be denied access. It's just that a different error message is provided.

Nevertheless, the issue is almost entirely irrelevant as you have a glaring hole in your `sudoers` definition that allows a trivial escape to root:

```
sudo -s
```

At this point you can do whatever you like without regard to `sudo`'s built-in controls anyway

Comment: (I cannot modify sudoers file. It's only allowed by the server master, I'm just one of the users.) When checked with `sudo -l`, `/bin/su [-] *` is allowed. And passing a variable which is contained in `env_keep` doesn't make any error. I want to know which file/line decides `su` not to allow passing a variable.

Comment: Like I said in your other question it doesn't really matter. The section trying to prevent certain commands being run _does not work_. Trying to fix the $PATH issue without adding that is like adding a lock to a window when the doorway next to it has no door